# angular material data table dependency not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

i'm following this step on the github 
https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table

i use rails asset to my gemfile
i follow the instruction here: https://rails-assets.org/#/components/angular-material-data-table

```
 gem 'rails-assets-angular-material-data-table'
```

and this is the dependency i follow in the github

```
#= require angular-animate
#= require angular-aria
#= require angular-messages
#= require angular-route
#= require angular-sanitize
#= require angular-cookies
#= require angular-material

#= require moment
#= require angular-moment
#= require angular-filter
#= require ng-rails-csrf
#= require angularjs-viewhead

#= require ./lib/ngDraggable

#= require angular-material-icons
#= require angular-material-data-table
#= require ./lib/jquery.flexslider
#= require ./lib/angular-flexslider

angular
 .module "App", ["ngAnimate", "ngAria", "ngMessages", "ngRoute",
              "ngSanitize", "ngCookies", "ngMaterial", "angularMoment",
              "angular.filter", "ng-rails-csrf", "viewhead",
              "ngDraggable", "ngMdIcons", "md.data.table", "angular-flexslider"]
```

i follow all the instruction but this gives me error??

```
Sass::SyntaxError - File to import not found or unreadable: md-data-table.
Load paths:
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/app/assets/config
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/app/assets/images
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/revampCAES/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ng-rails-csrf-0.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/doorkeeper-4.0.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/doorkeeper-4.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-smart-table-2.1.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-ng-file-upload-12.2.12/app/assets/flash
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-ng-file-upload-12.2.12/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-data-table-0.10.9/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-data-table-0.10.9/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-icons-0.6.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-icons-0.6.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-icons-0.6.0/app/assets/templates
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-lodash-3.10.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-file-upload-2.3.4/app/assets/documents
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-file-upload-2.3.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-file-model-0.3.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-jquery.browser-0.1.0/app/assets/documents
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-jquery.browser-0.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-fastclick-1.0.6/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-velocity-1.2.3/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-velocity-1.2.3/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-velocity-1.2.3/app/assets/templates
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-string-3.3.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-jquery.scrollTo-2.1.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-filter-0.5.11/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angularjs-viewhead-0.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angularjs-viewhead-0.0.1/app/assets/templates
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-translate-storage-local-2.12.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-translate-storage-cookie-2.12.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-translate-loader-partial-2.12.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-translate-loader-static-files-2.12.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-translate-2.12.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-moment-0.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-moment-2.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-cookies-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-sanitize-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-resource-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-route-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-1.1.1/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-1.1.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-material-1.1.1/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-messages-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-animate-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-aria-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.5.8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.5.8/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-jquery-2.1.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-respond-1.4.2/app/assets/images
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-respond-1.4.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-respond-1.4.2/app/assets/templates
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-html5shiv-3.7.3/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/js-routes-1.3.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/zeroclipboard-rails-0.1.2/app/assets/images
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/zeroclipboard-rails-0.1.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/ckeditor-2dfb02f29fd8/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/ckeditor-2dfb02f29fd8/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/ckeditor-2dfb02f29fd8/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/assets/compiled:
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:313:in `visit_import'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
  sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
  sass-rails (5.0.6) lib/sass/rails/template.rb:47:in `evaluate'
  tilt (2.0.5) lib/tilt/template.rb:102:in `render'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:196:in `dfs'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:92:in `[]'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:355:in `find_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:347:in `find_debug_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `lookup_debug_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:169:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
  app/views/shared/_head.html.slim:11:in `_app_views_shared__head_html_slim___458961673759728409_70167772754560'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:343:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:311:in `block in render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:3:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim__1030391115330471261_70167779026200'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  wicked_pdf (1.1.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:42:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
  wicked_pdf (1.1.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:36:in `default_render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  request_store (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'

Started POST "/__better_errors/2d3a8fa1c117d67e/variables" for ::1 at 2016-11-03 18:41:25 +0800
```

Comment: did you include the dependency in your index ?

Comment: yes i add my dependency